# Why does my thermal printer wastes half a meter of paper for each image?

Tags: java, printing

I am trying to print an image to a thermal printer ([Bixolon srp350 plus](http://www.bixolon.com/_eng/products/product_form.asp?uid=4)), using the Java jdk 1.6 PrintService API.

Although I am able to print it, the printer feeds continuously for some time and prints the image at the end.
About half a meter of paper is wasted every time I try to print the image using the code below.

```
DocAttributeSet das = new HashDocAttributeSet();    

das.add(new PrinterResolution(180,180,PrinterResolution.DPI));
PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();    
pras.add(new Copies(1));    
pras.add(new PrinterResolution(180,180,PrinterResolution.DPI)); 

PrintService pss[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.JPEG,pras);    
if (pss.length == 0)    {
    throw new RuntimeException("No printer services available."); 
}

PrintService ps = pss[0];
String imageResource = "logo.jpg";
DocPrintJob job = ps.createPrintJob();
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(imageResource);

    Doc imageDoc = new SimpleDoc(fis, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.JPEG, null);
    job.print(imageDoc,pras);
    fis.close();

} catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Just an idea: Could it be that your "page size" is configured to be around half a meter?

Comment: no because when i print it without the image , the printer prints fine. but when i try to print the image alone or with the print data . it waste about half a meter of  paper and starts printing the image.

Comment: What is the DPI of your image? Sometimes they are set to something insane.